# Shell script does not run: simple

Tags: shell

Writing a shell script to switch between ruby versions because currently my rvm setup requires me to write 2-3 lines to switch ruby versions, and im constantly doing this because im writing a ruby app which requires 2.2.1 and latex documents which requires ruby 1.9.1. My current code probably looks more like pseudocode, so please help me to get it to run. Here's the code:

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/bash --login
rvm list // this is an external shell command
echo -n Use which one? >
read text
rvm use $text // this is an external shell command
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That script is problematic since it will run `bash` as a login shell and then refuse to run any of those other lines until you exit it.

You probably don't need a shell script for what you're trying to do, just have two aliases set up in your profile:

```
alias rlist='rvm list'
alias ruse='rvm use'
```

Then you can enter `rlist` if you want a list of them, or `ruse 2.2.1` (for example) to select one.

---

Alternatively, as `Walter A` points out in a comment, you could also hard-code the possibilities assuming you don't want it too dynamic:

```
alias rbapp='rvm use 2.2.1'
alias rbltx='rvm use 1.9.1'
```

This has the added advantage of allowing you to do more things at the end if needed:

```
alias rbltx='rvm use 1.9.1; echo Using Latex ruby'
```

something that's not normally possible with aliases needing parameters.

Comment: Or make two aliasses for the two versions, something like appruby and latexruby.